# Return from a remote task flow

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf, bounded-types, adf-task-flow

[image]Is it possible to return from a remote task flow without having to specify a return control flow rule form the remote task flow to the consumer task flow (calling task flow) if there is a wildcard entry point defined in the calling task flow ?

Comment: what do you want to do? to return with value?

Answer (score 0):

I think you still HAVE to have the return, although upon return to the calling TF, its wildcard can cause navigation to another page/TF if the TF return passes back an outcome that can be evaluated.